# REST API quick response best practice

Tags: python, flask

Let's say I want a client to make a Post request, but not have to wait until the server does a time consuming task. So my code looks something like this.

```
@app.route(/url, methods = ['POST'])
def doSomething():
    thread(target = timeConsumingTask, args = get_data_from_post_request).start()
    return ''
```

Is there a better way, or a best practice for something like this ?

Answer (score -1):

This won't work. Can't say for sure but either the thread will die with the server process once it's done with request or the process will wait for thread to finish, hanging and doing you no good.

What you want is something like [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) or [python-rq](https://python-rq.org/)

Comment: Not sure why you downvote. Celery is industry standard for this, python-rq is a lightweight alternative